# Can't seem to Pass EventArgs By Reference

Tags: c#, vb.net, events, eventhandler, eventargs

I have a class that raises an event. I want the subscriber to be able to modify the values being passed in the EventArgs.

In the class that raises the events:

```
    class Factory
    {
    public event EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs> MessageReceived;

    private IServerLib _myObject;

    public void Connect()
    {
        _myObject = new ServerLib();
        _myObject.AddMessageReceivedHandler((short terminal, ref string message, ref short functionNo) =>
        {
            MessageReceivedEventArgs args = new MessageReceivedEventArgs { Terminal = terminal, Message = message, FunctionNo = functionNo };
            MessageReceivedEvent(ref args);
        });
    }

    private void MessageReceivedEvent(ref MessageReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs> handler = MessageReceived;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, args);
        }
    }

    public class MessageReceivedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public short Terminal { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public short FunctionNo { get; set; }
    }
}


interface IServerLib
    {
        void AddMessageReceivedHandler(MessageReceivedEventHandler action);
    }
    public delegate void MessageReceivedEventHandler(short terminal, ref string message, ref short functionNo);
```

The subscriber (which happens to be VB) looks like this:

```
Dim WithEvents _va As MyAssembly.MyClass

Private Sub _va_MessageReceived(sender As Object, e As Factory.MessageReceivedEventArgs) Handles _va.MessageReceived
    Debug.WriteLine($"Message: {e.Message} Terminal: {e.Terminal} Function: {e.FunctionNo}")
    If e.Message = "1" Then
        e.Message = ""
        e.FunctionNo = 0
        Debug.WriteLine("Cancelled")
    End If
End Sub
```

This raises the event, but setting the e.Message and e.Function do not seem to set the values. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you think that your "ref" parameters will be affected then yes - you are doing something wrong, they won't. Instead pass instance of MessageReceivedEventArgs to your MessageReceivedEvent.

Comment: @Evk - I believe I am doing that `handler(this, args);` `args` is an instance

Comment: You can show code that actually compiles? (Since `(short x, ref string y, ref short z) =>` isn't allowed, this code seems flawed.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - I will try to but I assure you that line is allowed as it compiles on my machine

Comment: Can you show `AddMessageReceivedHandler`? It gets a delegate of course...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the use of this line:

```
var args = new MessageReceivedEventArgs
           { Terminal = terminal, Message = message, FunctionNo = functionNo };
```

It copiex all variables to the event args class. Changing it there doesn't automatically change it on the other end (where you added `ref`). Not a nice solution, but to proof to you this is the issue, add this after `handler(this, args)`:

```
message = args.Message;
functionNo = args.FunctionNo;
```

This will cause the `ref`s to overwrite the values.

Comment: Ah yes - I see now. Do you know of any "nice" solution. This sort of thing is done by the framework in `CancelEventArgs` of FormClosing for example - do you know how that might be done?

Comment: Yes, and there they use the value inside the receiving method. The result is not passed outside the method boundaries (and if so, they use a return value probably)

Comment: This is actually a decent solution. You could pass in one object, instead of passing in values by reference.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you think that your "ref" parameters should be affected by the code above, but that is not true. Yes you pass your `message` by reference to `MessageReceivedEvent` function, but then you assign it to `MessageReceivedEventArgs.Message`, and this happens by value, not by reference.

In result, when you modify `MessageReceivedEventArgs.Message` in your VB code - `message` variable is not affected (but `MessageReceivedEventArgs.Message` *is* affected of course), despite that you passed it by reference, as it should be.

What you should do instead is passing instance of `MessageReceivedEventArgs` to your function directly (not creating it inside that function):

```
private void MessageReceivedEvent(MessageReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs> handler = MessageReceived;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: This still doesn't seem to work. I have now modified the argument as you suggested and created an instance of the MessageReceivedEventArgs in the Connect Method and passed this.

Comment: It should work, if It doesn't please update your question with new code (and clarify your goals).

Comment: Passing `args` doesn't help, since it still doesn't copy the `ref`s.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I meant completely different thing - get rid of all refs and use one instance of a agrs. Actually what you propose in comments to your answer. But after update to the question I see its not possible, because refs are in event signature.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Your answer pointed in the right direction though @Evk

Answer (score 0):

First off, you don't need `ref` in order to change a property of your `MessageReceivedEventArgs`. The object variable is just a pointer to the real object in memory so you already changing its properties. If you need your subscriber to change the reference itself - i.e. to reset the pointer to another object - then you need to use `ref`.
Second, this design is terrible thus I'm not sure I understand the problem. Anyway I'm going to provide a proper way to raise events and consume the changed values after that.

```
class Factory 
{
    public event EventHandler<MessagereceivedEventArgs> MessageReceived;

    void ReceiveMessage(string Message)
    {
        // Do something with the Message

        // Then let your subscribers know that the message has been processed:
        if (MessageReceived != null)
        {
            var ea = new MessageReceivedEventArgs();
            ea.Message = Message;
            // Set ea properties as appropriate 
            MessageReceived(this, ea);
            // Check ea properties for change
            if (ea.Message != Message)
            {
                // A subscriber has changed the message in the MessageReceivedEventArgs
            }
        }
    }
}
```